# Dojo Drag and Drop Issue: Convert Data in Target Container to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, drag-and-drop

I have two DND conatainers, SourceContainer and TargetContainer
SourceContainer have some json data e.g:

```
Apple 
Orange 
Banana
```

using following Json:

```
var json = {"fruits": [
           {"fruitId": 1, "fruitName": "Apple", "fruitDesc": "This is an Apple"},
           {"fruitId": 2, "fruitName": "Orange", "fruitDesc": "This is an Orange"},
           {"fruitId": 3, "fruitName": "Banana", "fruitDesc": "This is a Banana"}
        ]
    };

var results="";
   for(var i=0;i<json.fruits.length;i++){
     results += '<div class="dojoDndItem ">' + '<span style="visibility: hidden">' + json.fruits[i].fruitId + '</span>' + json.fruits[i].fruitName  + '</div>';
   }
```

**My SourceContainer**

```
<div><label>Fruits</label></div> 
<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" id="source1" copyonly="false" delay="8" class="container dojoDndSource dojoDndTarget dojoDndContainer">
<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" ></div> results </div>
```

**My TargetContainer**

```
<div><label>Basket</label></div>
<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source"  id="source2" copyonly="false" descending="true" delay="8" class="container dojoDndSource dojoDndTarget dojoDndContainer">
<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" ></div>
</div>

<button id="toJsonBtn" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="button">ToJson</button>
```

Now when I drag "Apple" and Banana to the TargetContainer and click the button, I want the data in TargetContainer to convert in Json.

Any idea for doing so. Appreciate any help. Thank you

**NOTE:** Force not to use JQuery :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out how to solve it. Below is the solution if some one interested;

**Our Json**

```
var json = {"fruits": [
               {"fruitId": 1, "fruitName": "Apple", "fruitDesc": "This is an Apple"},
               {"fruitId": 2, "fruitName": "Orange", "fruitDesc": "This is an Orange"},
               {"fruitId": 3, "fruitName": "Banana", "fruitDesc": "This is a Banana"}
            ]
        };
```

**Items in target container**

```
Apple 
Orange 
Banana
```

**Create Target Container**

```
var fruitListContainer = new dojo.dnd.Source("fruitNode");

dojo.connect(dojo.byId('toJsonBtn'), 'onclick', function() {
  var target_container = fruitListContainer.getAllNodes();
  var fruit_arr = [];
  for(var i=0;i<target_container.length;i++){
      var fruit_results = target_container[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      roles_arr.push(fruit_results);
  }
var result={};
result["fruits"]=fruit_arr;
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

And the alert output will be (which is required):

```
{"fruits":["Apple","Orange","Banana"]}
```

**Note:**  *If there any explanation needed, I am happy to help.*